# adb logcat is not saving logs in txt file using python

Tags: python-3.x, adb, android-logcat

I am using python:

```
import os
cmd = os.system('start "test1" cmd.exe adb logcat -b system *:V | tee sys.txt')
```

'tee' file logging is working fine. However, 'sys.txt' is not saving the logs in the txt file.
Following command is working fine and saving the logs when executed via cmd:

```
adb logcat -b system *:V | tee sys.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("adb logcat -b system *:V | tee sys.txt", shell=True)
```

without `shell=True` , everything after `adb` will be treat as `adb`'s parameters, not the shell parameters.